# I guess i am not going out of bound but still getting that error while solving SURROUNDED REGIONS problem on leetcode.Please help me out

Tags: c++, c++17

## getting error------->AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffdad997ff4 (pc 0x000000345ac1 bp 0x7ffdad998040 sp 0x7ffdad997fc0 T0)
==31==ABORTING.......Please help me out.THANKS IN ADVANCE

```
    bool dfs(int i,int j,int m,int n,vector<vector<char>>&v){
    if(i>=m||i<0||j>=n||j<0){
        return false;
    }
    if(v[i][j]=='X'){
        return true;
    }
    bool left=dfs(i,j-1,m,n,v);
    bool right=dfs(i,j+1,m,n,v);
    bool top=dfs(i-1,j,m,n,v);
    bool bottom=dfs(i+1,j,m,n,v);
    if(left&&right&&top&&bottom){
        
        v[i][j]='X';
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    
}
void solve(vector<vector<char>>& board) {
    int m=board.size();
    int n=board[0].size();
    for(int i=1;i<m-1;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<n-1;j++){
            if(board[i][j]=='O'){
               bool temp= dfs(i,j,m,n,board);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
    
}
```

Comment: You have an infinite recursion, which terminates only when the program runs out of stack space. E.g. `dfs(5, 5, ...)` calls `dfs(5, 4, ...)` which calls `dfs(5, 5, ...)` right back.

Comment: You need to keep track of which elements you have already visited.